# How do I determine the compatability level of a SQL 2005 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Simple question; How do you determine the compatibility level of a SQL Server 2005 database?
I've looked at the properties dialog in Sql Management Studio but can't find anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSMS it's in the properties page of the database in question under Options in the menu on the left.  3rd drop-down from the top underneath Collation and Recovery model.

You can also use `sp_dbcmptlevel` to check it via TSQL:

```
sp_dbcmptlevel 'DatabaseName'
```

60 = SQL 6.0
65 = SQL 6.5
70 = SQL 7.0
80 = SQL 2000
90 = SQL 2005
100 = SQL 2008

Comment: Brilliant, I was obviously being stupid to miss that!